# Firefox installation error

Tags: firefox

I am trying to install Firefox but there is error like;

```
Failed to fetch
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox_25.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.13.10.1_amd64.deb
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80] E: Unable to fetch some archives,
maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Also I tried software center but it said also;

```
Failed to download package files Check your Internet connection.
Failed to fetch
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox_25.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.13.10.1_amd64.deb
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
```

What is the problem for this basic operation?

Comment: maybe run `sudo apt-get update` or try with `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing` What happens? Edit the question to add information?

Comment: First I typed sudo apt-get update --fix-missing then I installed firefox and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no file there, so it's not gonna download obviously. Which version of Ubuntu do you have? Try running `sudo apt-get update` or download updates (see if they work, and from which server). If it doesn't work, download FF from `mozilla.org`.